# Number of connected components in a directed graph in GraphX

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, connected-components

I know graphx's `connectedComponents()` method will label each connected component of the graph with the ID of its lowest-numbered vertex. Is there a method call to count the number of connected components in graphx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `connectedComponents()` to get this count. First run the method on your graph, then count the number of unique `VertexId` that is in the result. In Scala:

```
graph.connectedComponents().vertices.map{ case(_,cc) => cc}.distinct.count()
```